# Data Architecture - Full Azure Stack vs Integrated Delta Lake

Tags: azure, databricks, delta-lake

A friend's company is working on a Data architecture which to us, it seems to be rather convoluted and having several scalability and cost problems.

If possible, I would like to have your opinion on the old and proposed architectures (or alternatives), to discuss their pros and cons and potentially finding unforeseen problems/limitations.

**Current Architecture - Azure Stack**

Ingestion Layer

- Multiple sources stored into *Azure Data Lake Gen2* *via Azure Databricks*

Processing Layer

- *Azure Databricks* cleans the data and stores them back into *Azure Data Lake Gen2* into different sections: raw, clean

Loading Layer

- *Azure Databricks* is used to load the data into a *Azure SQL Server* instance
- *Azure Synapse* is used as the layer between *Azure SQL Server* and *Azure Analysis Services*

Presentation Layer

- Data Models created in *Azure Analysis Services* and served into Power BI or Excel

Pros of this Approach

- Models and optimisation (OLAP) generated via *Azure Analysis Services*
- Fully integrated within the *Azure* ecosystem

Cons of this Approach

- Vertically scalable: as the data grows, so will the *Azure SQL Server* used to store the Data Warehouse grow vertically, as will the *Azure Analysis Services* required to process said data
- High Costs
- Convoluted: a lot of services serving as glue, harder to manage/maintain
- Always-on approach: both *Azure SQL Server* and *Azure Analysis Services* are required to be *always* on, representing unneeded expenses

**Proposed Architecture - Azure w/ Delta Lake**

The alternative architecture relies on the fact that *Azure Databricks* is already used within the ETL process and attempts to maximize its usage to provide horizontal scalability and Serverless resources.

Ingestion Layer

- (same) Multiple sources stored into *Azure Data Lake Gen2* *via Azure Databricks*

Processing and Loading Layers

- (same) *Azure Databricks* cleans the data and stores them back into *Azure Data Lake Gen2* into different sections: raw, clean
- *Azure Databricks* generates the Data Warehouse using *Delta Lake* storing it directly in *Azure Data Lake Gen2* creating Silver and Gold (Aggregation/Cubes) quality

Presentation Layer

- Using *Azure Synapse Analytics (Serverless)* to designate access and querying capabilities directly on *Azure Data Lake Gen2* which is then exposed to *Power BI* and *Excel* for Governance purposes

Pros of this Approach

- Simpler
- Horizontally scalable: the pipeline relies on *Azure Delta Lake Gen2* (Parquet), which is naturally horizontally scalable; and *Azure Synapse Analytics (Serverless)* which, due to its Serverless pool, can also be considered horizontally scalable-ish.
- Delta Lake provides a natural Audit layer and is easily integrated with existing Data Catalog solutions

Cons of this Approach

- No Data Models to facilitate usage via Power BI and Excel
- Critical to partition the Parquet files according to *Azure Synapse Analytics*'s queries else we may incur in high transfer costs
- No true OLAP capabilities

Answer (score 1):

I think almost you covered. Based on my experience giving few suggestion . You can consider this approach if your business model allows.

[image]

**Ingestion Layer:**

- Each team(business unit) should have different container for storage data. **Reason** : we can maintain access level in team level.
- Since any distribution environment, always ELT process is recommended than ETL , we can use Azure data factory as ingestion tool to build a data lake. **Reason** : Databricks is for computing purpose , no point in use for ingestion purpose.
- Each container should have 3 different folder in same container.
- In first layer , Stage - which hold incremental loads on daily basis from source .(Based on the frequency).
- So every time stage data will be appended in raw layer data .Finally Raw layer which will contain exact snap shot of source .
- we should maintain some curated folder , sometimes we may required to handle some secure data . that time we can isolate secure data from other data.

**Structure Layer :**

- In this Layer , we need to maintain the proper structured of the data.
  Take an example , Some time , we may required to maintain or convert from one format to another format. consider , one column has string type in source , but business need to convert string to decimal . those kind process should be taken care in this layer .
- we can handle this transformation through Azure Databricks.

**Serve Layer :**

- This is layer we will do all transformation for reporting layer . Example Team-1 and team-2 should be joined in this layer .
- we can handle this transformation through Azure Databricks

**Presentation Layer :**

- Using Azure Synapse Analytics (Serverless) to designate access and querying capabilities directly on Azure Data Lake Gen2 which is then exposed to Power BI and Excel for Governance purposes
- Or we can connect serve layer through Databricks cluster JDBC connection. So that, handling all access control very easy if connect reporting layer from databricks.